# putExtra() and getExtra() error in android

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I try to put my id and get it back threw getIntExtra() , when i putExtra of my id it logged to 93 but i get it back in new Activity it logged 0.

==> PutID

```
if (position == 1) {
        val intent = Intent(this, PreExamActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        intent.putExtra("cat_id", selectedCategoryId)
        Log.e("##", "=======set_cat_id======${selectedCategoryId}")
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

==> GetID

```
cat_id = intent.getIntExtra("cat_id", 0)
    Log.e("##", "=======getcatId====${cat_id}")
```

==> MyLog is :-

> E/##: =======set_cat_id======93
>   E/##: =======getcatId====0

Comment: This happens because it's getting the default value (the one you provided as a second argument to `getIntExtra`). It also means that your `Intent` doesn't have that extra.. how are you getting the intent?

Comment: Make sure the datatype of selectedCategoryId and cat_id is `int `

Answer (score 1):

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if(extras != null)
String data = extras.getString("cat_id");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check:

```
if (intent.hasExtra("cat_id")) {...}
```

if the code inside the brackets is not executed then there is no such extra value, and why?  
 What is the purpose of `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)`?  
From the documentation:

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP If set, and the activity being launched is
>   already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new
>   instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it
>   will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top)
>   old activity as a new Intent.

So if the activity you want to launch is already open, will not receive the extras you provide

Use this in the activity you want to open:

```
override fun  onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    setIntent(intent)

    // this is where you check for extras of intent
}
```